# What are $G$-foo sets really called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Here's a familiar concept:

- A $G$-acted set consists of a $X$ together with a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(X).$

We can also dualize:

- A $G$-foo set consists of a set $X$ together with a homomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(X) \rightarrow G$.

For example, suppose we're given a finite set $X$. Then $X$ becomes a $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$-foo set in a canonical way, by letting the morphism $\mathrm{Aut}(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ denote the [parity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation).

> **Question.** What are $G$-foo sets really called?

Comment: A co-$G{}$-set?

Comment: The dual notion is that of a cogroup coacting on something. This is something else entirely.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, don't be silly. There are often many ways of dualizing any given definition.

Comment: Symmetric groups don't have very many homomorphic images BTW.